# Understanding the purpose of closures

Tags: swift, function, closures

Trying to Understand Swift Closures

I am trying to get my head around how closures work and when they should be used. There are a few things that I don't understand...

1. How do I know what to name my return type? In my example below... neither 'action' or 'alertTextField' are just returned.
2. What needs to go inside the closure? Why can this not just be done in a function so that people reading the code can see what is being called and where? (You can tell I simply dont understand their need)
3. Did you struggle to learn closures? How did you go about understanding. Did someone teach them to you in a way that made it click in your head?

```
    @objc func addButtonPressed() {

        var textField = UITextField()

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "What do you need to do?", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let alert = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in
            self.itemArray.append(textField.text!)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        alertController.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            textField = alertTextField
        }

        alertController.addAction(alert)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: closure **is** a function. It's just a function you define inline. It's far better to see the functionality in place where it is used than having a function on different place and having to scroll back and forth to see the connection.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I know what to name my return type? In my example below... neither 'action' or 'alertTextField' are just returned.

When you write the code the auto-complete should tell you what is the type of the closure return value , adding a descriptive name is the way to go

[image]

> What needs to go inside the closure? Why can this not just be done in a function so that people reading the code can see what is being called and where? (You can tell I simply dont understand their need)

Inside the closure you should write the code that do something e.x when the alert action is clicked ( user clicks ok or cancel ) and sure you could write a function and call it from inside it

> Did you struggle to learn closures? How did you go about understanding. Did someone teach them to you in a way that made it click in your head?

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Answer (score 0):

You can look at closures same as at functions. In Swift closure and functions have a same type. But functions have names and do not capture variables in around scope.
You wrote a short syntax of a closure, in a complete syntax a closure has list of parameters, capture list, and return value. The complete syntax is too verbose:

```
{ [weak self] (a : AClass) -> BClass in

  return BClass()
}
```

You can omit the return type, parameters types, and capture list, compiler infer it via context.
By default, a closure captures variables by strong references for classes, and by references for structures (you can modify value of structure's instances from closure).

```
var s = Struct()
let closure = {
  s.a = 5;
}
closure()
```

About async calling of closures

> A closure is said to escape a function when the closure is passed as
>   an argument to the function, but is called after the function returns.

This means that the closure will have strong references for all variables that is mentioned in the closures body. To avoid strong references with self, I use next trick:

```
let closure = { [weak self] () -> Void in
 guard let self = self else {
  return
 }
 //do some work
}
```

Look at closures as at functions without name or as at functor (in term of C++) that is created by a compiler and all will be ok.

[Here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) you can read about syntaxes of closures. Also closures in swift same with blocks in Objective-C, and lambdas in C++.